# storing entire facebook graph object into a php session

Tags: php, session, facebook-graph-api

I'm pretty new to php sessions so I'm not sure about how they're used in industry, best practises etc.

I use file_get_contents to get the facebook stream data for my page and then use php to parse the json and display on the page. however i noticed a serious lag in my website obviously due to the fact that everytime the page loads, it fetches the facebook stream, parses and THEN returns the html.

So I was thinking of ways to speed up the process so my page loading time doesn't suffer (because my facebook stream will be on EVERY page in my website) And i came up with this simple code:

```
<div id="FacebookFeed">
    <h1>Facebook</h1>
    <?
        if (isset($_SESSION["fbFeed"])){
            $fbFeed = $_SESSION["fbFeed"];
        }
        else {
            $fbFeedURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/***/feed?access_token=***&limit=1";
            $fbFeedString = file_get_contents($fbFeedURL);
            $fbFeed = json_decode($fbFeedString);
            unset($fbFeedString);
            $_SESSION["fbFeed"] = $fbFeed;
        }
        if ($fbFeed != null){
    ?>
    <p><? var_dump($fbFeed);?></p>
    <?  } ?>
</div>
```

so basically if the "fbFeed" session is set, I use that(in the hope it would be quicker than fetching the data on every page) and if its not set, I set it. SIMPLE'S!

but is it a good idea saving all that data in a session? is that what theyre usually used for or is it only small amounts of data that are passed from page to page?

also any optimisation tips would be helpful!

Thanks, Alex

Comment: how did you get on with this in the end?

Comment: I pulled the info I needed example just the name, post message, maybe a link if it existed, and stored it in a session! On page load, if the session existed, use the session data. if not, fetch the data. This means the first time you load the page, it takes about 3 seconds. all subsequent times. its pretty darn fast ;) I would have gone for the database option however i was only fetching ONE post

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that it's fine to do this, but potentially the stream could take up a lot of memory or contain errors that will persist for the session.

How about importing the returned data into your database periodically? You could have a table that always contained the latest *n* posts etc. If the update fails, then you still have your previous 'clean' data.

In terms of optimisation, you can gain some performance from using cURL to get the data, something like this:

```
$feed = null;
$curl = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/***/feed?access_token=***&limit=1');

// check that it's a valid resource
if (is_resource($curl) === true) {
  // setup options
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  // execute session and then close it
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  // attempt to json decode if we get a valid response
  if ($response) {
    $feed = json_decode($response, true);
  }
}

// if valid feed
if ($feed) {
  var_dump($feed);
}
```